# How to get the module name from the alias

Tags: python

Given

```
import a_long_module_name as short_name
```

Is there a way of obtaining the name of the module from the alias, so I can

```
x=something(short_name)
print(x)
>> a_long_module_name
```

Thanks!

Comment: `short_name.__name__`? Note: it's often helpful to inspect Python objects with [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) - that also applies for imported packages.

Comment: for more information read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__name__#import-related-module-attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example with numpy

```
import numpy as np

print (np.__name__)
```

It prints "numpy"